# Azure AD: limit consumer's access to particular Web APIs

Tags: api, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using Microsoft Azure. I have published several Web APIs. Each has  Authentication / Authorization turned on, with Azure Active Directory (AAD) as the sole provider. We have a single AAD tenant.

The consumers will be partner companies' applications. For each consumer I have created an App Registration in AAD. Using that App Registration's Application ID and Key I can successfully get a token and call the Web APIs (tested through Postman).

My problem is that every consumer credential can access every API. I want to restrict a consumer's access to specific APIs only. For example, consumer A can access API P and Q; consumer B can access API Q and R. There is some overlap, and some uniqueness. I have been trough the online docs. They mention very little about this service-to-servie scenario. I can find no example code matching my scenario. How do I enforce consumer to API mapping in an AAD single tenant?

Answer (score 0):

In service-to-servie scenario , the simplest way is writing your own validation logic on web api side .

After getting the access token on web api side , checking the client id(`appid` claim) in access token , if that client is not allowed to access the web api , denied it and return the error response .

Another way is checking the application roles :

1. in your web api app , setting the application roles in Manifest like :

   ```
   "appRoles": [
   {
     "allowedMemberTypes": [
       "Application"
     ],
     "displayName": "tester",
     "id": "9f29f99b-5c77-4fba-a310-4a5c0572e8ff",
     "isEnabled": true,
     "description": "read client app",
     "value": "tester"
   }
   ```

   ]
2. In you client app  registered in Azure Portal, grant related application permission in `Required permissions` blade . Don't forget to do admin consent by clicking `Grant Permissions` button(login with admin's account) after adding application permissions .
3. In your code of web api , check access using the IsInRole() or the [Authorize] attribute after configuring the roles claim type in Startup file .

You could refer to [this document](http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/) which explains and shows the detail steps . Please refer to `Configuring client application to request application roles of resource API` section .